# SharedPreferences in static method - Lint warning "might be null" despite passing a defaultValue?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a static method for retrieving the database instance:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
GlobalVariables.appVersion = sharedPreferences.getString(GlobalVariables.SHARED_PFC_APP_VERSION_KEY, GlobalVariables.APP_VERSION_HOW);

return makeInstance(context, GlobalVariables.appVersion);
```

The GlobalVariables class is completely static and all variables are final static too.

Now Lint gives me a warning that the second argument in `return makeInstance(context, GlobalVariables.appVersion)` might be null.
How can that be? **Am I not passing a *static* default value for when nothing is found in the SP?**

It can't be the GlobalVariables value itself, since those are all static and it works if I simply assign it to appVersion without the SP.
I suspected it might be because of the `context`argument, but even an `if != null` safety check does not remove this warning.

Does that mean that the `SharedPreferences` instance can be null in that case?

What is causing it and how can I make it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can that be?

The `getString()` method is marked as returning a `@Nullable` value.

> Am I not passing a static default value for when nothing is found in the SP?

That does not change the fact that the `getString()` method is marked as returning a `@Nullable` value. Lint has no idea that in this particular circumstance the method could not possibly return `null`.

> how can I make it safe?

Assuming that `GlobalVariables.APP_VERSION_HOW` is not `null`, it is safe already.

Comment: But is there ever a case in which `getString()` could return null? Does it not always get a default value passed into it? I am confused as to why it would be nullable. Also, what's the correct way to get rid of the warning, simply assert `!= null`?

Comment: @Big_Chair: "But is there ever a case in which getString() could return null?" -- sure: `getString("key", null)`. "Does it not always get a default value passed into it?" -- and that default value could be `null`. "Also, what's the correct way to get rid of the warning" -- there is something about `GlobalVariables.APP_VERSION_HOW` that is causing Lint to think that it might be `null`. The only way I can get that warning to appear is by hard-coding `null` (`getString("key", null)`).